# Is there a way to update dict values with array values?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm currently working with the following code:

```
def ability_stat_roll():
    stat_rolls_stored = []
    for i in range(6):
        stat_rolls = []
        for j in range(4):
            num = random.randint(1, 6)
            stat_rolls.append(num)
        del stat_rolls[stat_rolls.index(min(stat_rolls))]
        stat_rolls_stored.append(sum(stat_rolls))
        stat_rolls_stored.sort(reverse=True)
    print(stat_rolls_stored)


ability_stat_roll()
```

Which would result in a list like below: (For example)

```
stat_array = [15, 14, 13, 12, 10, 8]
```

What I'm trying to figure out is is there a way to take the values from the list and input into a dict for a more user friendly way, example of dict below:

```
stat_dict = {"str": 0, "dex": 0, "con": 0, "int": 0, "wis": 0, "cha": 0}
```

I have attempted to try to do the `Update Dict` function but I keep getting errors that it's not valid form of `Update Dict`. I don't want to append the list as the dict value above already has keys that I would want. Is there a function that would be able to update the dict values from a list?

What I want the end result to be is the following:

```
"str": 15, "dex": 14, "con": 13, "int": 12, "wis": 10, "cha": 8
```

Is this possible to do? I'm new to Python and just trying to get my hands wet with trying to create different types of programs.

Answer thanks to the comment below:

```
def ability_stat_roll():
    stat_rolls_stored = []
    for i in range(6):
        stat_rolls = []
        for j in range(4):
            num = random.randint(1, 6)
            stat_rolls.append(num)
        del stat_rolls[stat_rolls.index(min(stat_rolls))]
        stat_rolls_stored.append(sum(stat_rolls))
        stat_rolls_stored.sort(reverse=True)
    print(stat_rolls_stored)

    null_stat_dict = {"str": 0, "dex": 0, "con": 0, "int": 0, "wis": 0, "cha": 0}

    for i, stat in zip(null_stat_dict, stat_rolls_stored):
        null_stat_dict[i] += stat
    print(null_stat_dict)


ability_stat_roll()
```

Which when ran the below is the result:

```
[17, 13, 12, 11, 10, 4]
{'str': 17, 'dex': 13, 'con': 12, 'int': 11, 'wis': 10, 'cha': 4}
```

Comment: That is a *list* not an array... but something like `for key, random_value in zip(stat_dict, stat_array): stat_dict[key] = random_value` would work, as a dictionary comprehension (just sugar): `{key: random_value for key, randome_value in zip(stat_dict, stat_array)}`

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the OP needs to show some effort.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can zip those two and add the number in `stat_array` to its corresponding key in `stat_dict`:

```
for k, num in zip(stat_dict, stat_array):
     stat_dict[k] += num
```

Output:

```
{'str': 15, 'dex': 14, 'con': 13, 'int': 12, 'wis': 10, 'cha': 8}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a dictonary and an array of the same length and both are ordered you can step through them both and update the values like this:

```
for index, key in enumerate(stat_dict.keys()):
    stat_dict[key] = stat_array[index]
```

To update a single element in the dictonary you use the key as an index like this:

```
stat_dict['int'] = 99
stat_dict['str'] = stat_array[0]
```

Comment: use `zip`, not `enumerate`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Either way works fine and both are about equally readable.

Comment: @Antimon I disagree, `zip` would be the most idiomatic, it's entire purpose is to do exactly this.

Comment: If you want to go idiomatic, ditch the for loop and use `dict(zip(stat_dict, stat_array))`.